# DB-agnostic Node.js code

Tags: node.js, nosql

I have some node.js code that connects to CouchDB and now I'm exploring other NoSQL databases (DynamoDB, MongoDB, etc).

Is there a DB-agnostic module that would allow me to switch NoSQL databases without much trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure you will need to change your code to adapt to a new database.

Anyways, there are a few options that allow you to switch from one of other database easily.

If you consider building from scratch, [Loopback](https://loopback.io/) has a juggler that allows to setup each model to connect to a different database. If you want to include it as a module in your app. probably you are looking something like [Waterline](http://waterlinejs.org/).

I have only used Loopback, it's great.

I haven't used Waterline.